# Adding DTLS support to netty

Tags: netty, dtls

Could some one give me some insights about adding DTLS support to Netty?
Whether Netty is using openSSL for supporting TLS and related ?

regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Netty uses either the JDK ssl imply or openssl based one depending on what you specify as dependency. That said there is currently no support for DTLS built-in.